# unable to set backgroundColor Transparent using screenOptions in React Naitve for iOS(React Navigation 6)

Tags: ios, react-native

I am using custom drawer for my app where i am trying to keep the backgroundColor Transparent for which i tried the screenOptions as below but it is giving me white background for iOS. If anybody have gone through this issue then please help me fix this one. In android it is working fine as expected.

```
screenOptionsProps = {
    screenOptions: {
        drawerStyle: {
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width*0.6, 
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
        },
        headerShown: false,
    },
}
```

CustomDrawerContent

```
const CustomDrawerContent = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        </View>
    )
}
```

I tried to find solution elsewhere too but not able to find anything suitable.

Comment: backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)'

Comment: I tried your suggestion, the white background turned to gray.

Comment: found solution through github issues https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8014. The solution is provided by @evgenyshenets in comments. We need to add drawerType: 'front' in screenOptions Drawer.Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give a try as below?

```
sceneContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'}}
```

Comment: I tried it already but did not work.